# How to detect local ip address

Tags: php

this is my code to detect my system ip Address

```
<?php

if ($_POST['login']) {

    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phnoe = $_POST['phnoe'];
    $ipd = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if (mysql_query("Insert Into nennetwork (name, email, password, phone, useripp ) Values ('$uname', '$email', '$pass', '$phnoe', '$ipd' )"))
        $pdmsg = "New Member Added!!";
}
```

and my IP is 192.168.7.16 but it is giving server address like 
   103.18.164.206..
i want my System's Ip
Is it possible???

Comment: use `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`

Comment: You cannot get a client's IP with PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];`

> `$_SERVER` is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here. That said, a large number of these variables are accounted for in the » CGI/1.1 specification, so you should be able to expect those.

**Extra Knowledge**

1. `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` - gives `http://192.168.0.1/index.php`
2. `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` - gives `www.example.com`
3. `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` - gives `127.0.0.1`
4. `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` - also gives `127.0.0.1`

**EDIT 01**

```
$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)) {
    $ipAddress = array_pop(explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']));
}
```

Comment: No it is inserting the host address

Comment: ok this is giving a he host address, but the IP i have mentioned is my Computer's internet IP address.

Comment: @Moderator its not true. assume I have access to internet and my ip address it `2.187.xx.xx` and my network ip is `192.168.2.1`. I ran a wamp server on `192.168.2.20` and I access it from my computer's browser. **What code shows the ip `192.168.2.1` ?**

Comment: @Moderator       no!! still not

Comment: @ashlliza is what im saying true? is that your case? cause I tested my assuming case and .. its working! `REMOTE_ADDR` is working and i get `192.168.2.1` !

Comment: @TechJS yes you are right, but REMOTE_ADDR is not working as i have mentioned

Comment: @ashlliza what is the url of the page? could you tell us? is it like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/mypage.php` ??

Comment: Well its an admin page so , cant give , e codes are giving the address of the url, although i want my network's ip

Comment: @ashlliza - I could be wrong but don't think you can get a clients network address in PHP only the external (internet) address

Comment: @ashlliza happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

As it seems your page is hosted on an internet network (for example ip of the server is `2.178.x.x`). In this case what I can say is that you **cant**.

Web Servers can not access inside of the user's network. for example, you have a wifi modem and 3 people are connected. the webserver can only sees your outer (internet) ip address not the inner (in wifi network, sth like `192.168.x.x`)

So the answer is: you cant.